# Как сделать видеотрансляцию на своём сайте без использования сервисов-посредников

Tags: веб-программирование, видео

Задача: организовать трансляцию с видео- или веб-камеры на своём сайте. При этом должна быть возможность большого числа одновременных просмотров; чтобы не перегружать компьютер, к которому подключена камера (и особенно - чтобы не перегружать интернет-канал этого компьютера), система должна быть двухступенчатой: с камеры видео идёт в один поток на хостинг, где лежит сайт; там его принимает программа-проигрыватель и оттуда уже раздаёт зрителям. Словом, примерно то же, что делают многочисленные сервисы онлайн-телевещания (yatv.ru и иже с ним), но не через сторонний сервис, а через программу на собственном сайте.

Желательно, чтобы решение не требовало установки на хостинге дополнительных компонентов (например, RTMP-сервера).

Я пробовал связку VLC media player (на компьютере с камерой) и Flowplayer (на сайте); настройки делал по инструкции: http://tehnolux.com.ua/index.php?route=information/news&news_id=4. Однако этот вариант не заработал. Всё ли верно в этой инструкции? Может быть, есть какие-то моменты, которые там пропущены или указаны ошибочно?

Есть ли другие варианты кодировщика/плейера? Как их установить и настроить?

Comment: В VLC+FlowPlayer все похоже на правду. Укажите, что не заработало. Предварительно определить кто виноват можно, открыв поток не FlowPlayer'ом, а вторым VLC, скормив ему адрес (http://...).

Comment: drdaeman, на этапе, когда я проверяю работу с локального компьютера (указав плейеру адрес http://localhost:7777), в плейере не отображается видео (или, реже, появляется один неподвижный кадр), а звук сначала идёт с перерывами, а потом вовсе исчезает. При попытке просмотреть с сайта - вообще нет ни изображения, ни звука.

Comment: Когда открываю поток вторым VLC, он отображается, но изображение с кошмарными артефактами и сильная задержка трансляции (причём разная для видео и аудио: звук заметно обгоняет картинку). Это при том, что источник и приёмник на одном и том же компьютере; что же будет при работе через сеть?
На правах безумной версии: может ли быть проблема в том, что камера даёт слишком качественную картинку, которая просто не успевает толком обрабатываться в реальном времени?

Comment: попробовал реализовать из примера трансляцию, такая же песня - тормоза и разваливание картинки. связаны они в основном с перекодирование в flv налету, надо искать оптимальные параметры перекодировки, битрейт снижать, например.

Comment: Мне кажется Ваш вопрос не конструктивным. Что значит не используя посредников? Берете мануал по протоколу передачи данных курите его и пишете свой плеер потокового видео! Только так Вы откажетесь от посредников.

Comment: Разная полезная информация по этим вопросам есть в бесплатном справочник по видеотрансляциям [http://itmultimedia.ru/spravochnik-po-videotranslyaciyam](http://itmultimedia.ru/spravochnik-po-videotranslyaciyam)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант есть разные. Например, на основе [Darwin Streaming Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Streaming_Server).

- [Пример установки и настройки](http://www.iupui.edu/~nmstream/live/howtoquicktime.html).
- [Видео с примером использования](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj7cYR9PGho)

Comment: В этом варианте мне не нравится, что «To view the stream, a user must have QuickTime Player». Желателен вариант, требующий только html+flash (всё-таки флеш-плейеры для видео — стандарт де-факто, а квиктаймов у конечного пользователя запросто может и не стоять).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с помощью приложения на телефон (IP WebCam) можно вывести видео с камеры, а в некоторых программах даже и звук. Заходите по айпи который выдала программа, и через консоль с компа достаете код. Там ставите его на свой сайт

Answer (score 1):

*Извините, если не совсем "профессиональный" ответ у меня, да и вопрос уже от 12 года, так что все наверное сильно изменилось. Но тем не менее для тех, кто как и я ищет ответ на аналогичные вопросы.*

Проще всего уже воспользоваться существующими платформами. Из моего исследования - это www.livestream.com, www.dacast.com]. Но там на английском и платно-дорого (достаточно дорого)

Из русскоязычных - [www.facecast.net](http://www.facecast.net), там трансляции от 990 р начинаются и настраиваются минут за 10 (тест бесплатно). Я (девушка, не профи) одну сама сделала без проблем для рекламы нашей настолки. И билеты можно продавать. Но там тоже есть свои нюансы... Поэтому если у кого есть еще рекомендации с *русскоязычными* сайтами для трансляций - буду благодарна за наводку на baritsa () mail ru

(ютюб не рассматриваю, потому что хочу музыку использовать, а они блокируют трансляцию из-за авторских прав)

Comment: Нашла еще Comdi, но у них еще дороже.